# What's the chemical nature of a dishwasher's rinsing agent?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, surfactants

It seems that a rinsing agent helps the dishes in the dishwasher dry much better than they do without it (which I recently noted on my new dishwasher). What molecules are used in the composition of these rinsing agents? How do they help the plates dry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [MSDS](http://www.rbnainfo.com/MSDS/US/Finish-Dishwasher-Cleaner.pdf) for Jet Dry (a common brand name) it contains:

- Sodium 2-phenylpropane-2-sulfonate (Sodium cumene sulfonate)
- Propane-1,2-diol
- Citric acid

I think it may be safe to assume that the citric acid is in there for a "clean" smell and also to soften the water (thanks to the commenter).  The sulfonate is presumably a surfactant to help break the surface tension of the water, and promote evaporation, and the propylene glycol may help serve as a coolant (and is favored due to low toxicity).

Comment: Right, the first component is a surfactant. Since presumably this will be used without caring for whether the dishwater is hard or soft, you do not want to use the ester of a fatty acid here. The sulfonate, which is the conjugate base of a relatively strong acid, will tend to be more soluble, and will not form scum with hard water ions.

Comment: The citric acid is there to soften water by converting calcium, iron, magnesium (and others) salts into the more soluble citrates, which also decreases the likelihood of scum.

Comment: Citric acid does not really smell.  I also don't see how propylene glycol would serve as a coolant.